# Getting error while running apt-get update

Tags: apt, keys

I am getting the following error while running  `apt-get update` on all of the servers.

```
W: A error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used.
Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 8B48AA6247928553
W: Some index files failed to download, they have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

The solutions available are:

```
 To login into each of the server and run the following command to import the gpg key for that repo.

 sudo gpg --keyserver hkp://subkeys.pgp.net --recv-keys 8B48AA6247928553
 sudo gpg --export --armor 8B48AA6247928553 | sudo apt-key add -
```

But this requires logging into all of the individual servers and run the above two commands.

I am looking for a way to correct by working on apt-repo server. Is there any way to do that.

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to add gpg keys for apt repositories is using `apt-key`. **You must trust the issuer of the key, otherwise your server will be likely compromised.**

```
wget -qO - http://some.server/archive.key | sudo apt-key add -
```

Or, if you downloaded the key:

```
sudo apt-key add key.gpg
```

If you are using Ubuntu, you can use `add-apt-repository`:

```
sudo add-apt-repository http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu main
```

Comment: Does this needs to be done on each machine ?